builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) generates invalid path (mix of Windows and Linux) for dotnet-isolated, Linux Azure Function app
I have deployed an Azure Function app on Linux using .NET 8 (dotnet-isolated).
When configuring the application configuration, I start by setting the base path using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().
However, at runtime (Azure only, not locally!), the appsettings.json file cannot be found. The generated path is a combination of Windows and Linux: '/tmp/functions\standby\wwwroot/appsettings.json'
Why do I observe this behavior, and how can it be fixed?
Error:
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The expected physical path was '/tmp/functions\standby\wwwroot/appsettings.json'.

.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.19.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.58.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="appsettings.development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>



You need to add the file references in .csproj file.

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_79001498</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


I have the same code in program.cs file alike you and given code in function.cs file to fetch the value.

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace _79001498
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            _logger.LogInformation("Current Directory: {currentDirectory}", currentDirectory);

            string name = _configuration["ConnectionStrings:name"];
            _logger.LogInformation("Name from appsettings.json: {name}", name);

            return new OkObjectResult($"Welcome to Azure Functions! Directory: {currentDirectory}, Name: {name}");
        }
    }
}


Then, I deployed this code to Linux isolated function app. I am able to get this function working without any error.



Thank you, but I already have the file references there. If any case, the resulting path shouldn't depend on whether files are included or not

@Shuzheng Can you share your function code?

Done - I have added it to the question

I think you have shared program.cs file instead function code

It was only Program.cs that used Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() for setting the base path for loading appsettings.json etc.

@Shuzheng I have deployed my function to app service plan function app and got the expected response.

But why would missing file references in .csproj mess up the path? It doesn’t make sense?

Try to use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() only without adding any appsettings file
